# Node.js JSON extract certain data

Tags: json, node.js

I'm trying to get certain data from a json link: 
bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-DRS

in my node IRC bot using:
https://www.npmjs.org/package/node.bittrex.api

Part of the code:

```
var url = ('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-DRS');

bittrex.options({
    'apikey' : settings.ticker.apikey,
    'apisecret' : settings.ticker.secretkey,
    'stream' : false,
    'verbose' : false,
    'cleartext' : true,
});
   case 'ticker':
    var user = from.toLowerCase();
    bittrex.sendCustomRequest(url, function(ticker, err) {
    if(err) {
      winston.error('Error in !ticker command.', err);
      client.say(channel, settings.messages.error.expand({name: from}));
      return;
    }
    winston.info('Fetched Price From BitTrex', ticker);
    client.say(channel, settings.messages.ticker.expand({name: user, price: ticker}));
   });
   break;
```

It works but outputs in IRC

```
[1:21am] <nrpatten> !ticker
[1:21am] <DRSTipbot> nrpatten The current DRS price at BitTrex {"success":true,"message":"","result":{"Bid":0.00000155,"Ask":0.00000164,"Last":0.00000155}}
```

I have used a couple of things to get it to show only "Last" from the reply but i keep getting errors.

Or get certain data from https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries

Like any info i want from:

`{"MarketName":"BTC-DRS","High":0.00000161,"Low":0.00000063,"Volume":280917.11022708,"Last":0.00000155,"BaseVolume":0.33696054,"TimeStamp":"2014-10-04T15:14:19.66","Bid":0.00000155,"Ask":0.00000164,"OpenBuyOrders":33,"OpenSellOrders":138,"PrevDay":0.00000090,"Created":"2014-06-18T04:35:38.437"}`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've parsed the JSON (e.g. via `JSON.parse(str);`), you just use whatever property name you want to get at. For example:

```
var info = JSON.parse('{"MarketName":"BTC-DRS","High":0.00000161,"Low":0.00000063,"Volume":280917.11022708,"Last":0.00000155,"BaseVolume":0.33696054,"TimeStamp":"2014-10-04T15:14:19.66","Bid":0.00000155,"Ask":0.00000164,"OpenBuyOrders":33,"OpenSellOrders":138,"PrevDay":0.00000090,"Created":"2014-06-18T04:35:38.437"}');
console.log(info.Bid);
```

Also, on an unrelated matter, typically callback parameters follow the error-first format (e.g. `(err, result)` instead of `(result, err)`) in order to be consistent with node core and most other modules on npm.